# Which avatar of Vishnu took place in the twenty first yuga?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, skanda-purana

In the Skanda Purana, Prabhasa kanda, chapter 19 there is a list of incarnations of Vishnu. It mentions an avatar to kill the asuras in the 21st dwapara yuga.

> Verse 79-80:
>   It was in the twenty-first Dvapara towards its close. When Dharma was
>   spoiled Visnu was born in the Vrsni dynasty. He was born in order to 
>   establish Dharma. He destroyed the Asuras.

Any ideas?

I checked the sanskrit manuscript. The translation are accurate for this chapter in https://archive.org/details/67SkandaPurana.Vol.19_201802/page/n128

Sanskrit verses can be found here: 
https://archive.org/details/SkandaPuranaVolume7PrabhasaKhandaVenkateswaraSteamPress1909/page/n63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verse 78-80 of Skanda Purana is as follows:

> Verse 78-80: **He was born of Devaki and Vasudeva** with Brahmagarga as leader (priest, preceptor). It was in the twenty-first Dvapara towards its close. When Dharma was spoiled **Visnu was born in the Vrsni dynasty**. He was born in order to establish Dharma. He destroyed the Asuras.

There are two points which I have highlighted, one is, it says son of Devaki and Vasudeva that is Lord Krishna as mentioned in many scriptures including [Mahabharata, Adi Parva: SECTION LXIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01064.htm).

> And Vishnu himself, of world-wide fame, and worshipped of all the worlds, was born of Devaki through Vasudeva, for the benefit of the three worlds.

And the second highlighted thing is that that Skanda Purana verse is saying that Vishnu is born in Vrishni dynasty. Lord Krishna is of Vrishni dynasty as mentioned in [Shrimad Bhagavaan, Canto 1, Chapter 3, Verse 23](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/23).

> ekonaviṁśe viṁśatime
>    vṛṣṇiṣu prāpya janmanī
>   rāma-kṛṣṇāv iti bhuvo
>    bhagavān aharad bharam
>
> In the nineteenth and twentieth incarnations, the Lord advented Himself as Lord Balarāma and Lord Kṛṣṇa in the family of Vṛṣṇi [the Yadu dynasty], and by so doing He removed the burden of the world.

So, that verse of Skanda Purana is talking about Lord Krishna but the only confusion is it says in 21st Dvapara while I used to know it as 28th Dvapara. I am not sure of it.

Comment: There is verse before it and after which are about Lord Krishna in 28th Dvapara. However, in the middle we see this mention of 21st yuga. Is it possible that Lord Parasurama killed the Kshatriyas in 21st yuga because he was born in 19th yuga.

Comment: @sidharthchhabra The verse before it is saying that Vyasa is born in 28th Dvapara. Lord Parashurama is not of Vrishni race he is of Bhargava race.

Comment: @sidharthchhabra And also in verse 74-77 it says Jamadagnya is born in 19th Treta yuga. Jamadagnya is son of Jamadagni I.e. Parashurama.

Comment: that's exactly what I said above there

Comment: @sidharthchhabra Its saying Vyasa is born in 28th Dvapara and Krishna in 21st while you are saying Krishna in 28th.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The verse before is talking about Vyasadev in 28th Dvapara and this verse is saying an Incarnation akin to Krishna in the twenty first. My mistake in the previous comment.

Comment: I guess our conclusion is that this may be a case of text corruption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89987/discussion-between-triyugi-narayan-mani-and-sidharth-chhabra).